# greeting.id is null or $scope.greeting is null

Tags: angularjs

I tested the restful web service and it has data:
http://localhost:8081/PetStoreSpringRest/rest/emps

This is the data:
[{"id":1,"name":"Albert Lam","createdDate":1484969286677},{"id":2,"name":"John John","createdDate":1484969286677}]

Using google chrome debugging I can see value for response.data
But for    window.alert($scope.greeting.id); it show null

The outcome of this

The ID is {{greeting.id}}

is
The ID is

Not sure why I have null in greeting.id and $scope.greeting.id is null

```js
    <!doctype html>
    <html ng-app="demo">
     <head>
      <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
      <script src="libs/angular.js"></script>
        
     <script>
     /*
     {"id":60,"content":"Hello, World!"} 
     http://localhost:8081/PetStoreSpringRest/rest/emps
     [{"id":1,"name":"Albert Lam","createdDate":1484969286677},{"id":2,"name":"John John","createdDate":1484969286677}]
     */
     angular.module('demo', [])
     .controller('Hello', function($scope, $http) {
         $http.get('http://localhost:8081/PetStoreSpringRest/rest/emps').
      then(function(response) {
          $scope.greeting = response.data;
          window.alert($scope.greeting.id);
      });
     });
     </script>
     </head>

     <body>
      <div ng-controller="Hello">
       <p>The ID is {{greeting.id}}</p>
       
       
       
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to return an array, so you must do something like `<p>The ID is {{greeting[0].id}}</p>`

Answer (score 0):

Your response is..

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Albert Lam","createdDate":1484969286677},{"id":2,"name":"John John","createdDate":1484969286677}]
```

Get all id's

```
<div ng-controller="Hello">
<div ng-repeat="x in greeting">
<p>The ID is {{x .id}}</p>
</div>
</div>
```

For particular ID

```
<div ng-controller="Hello">
<p>The ID is {{greeting[0].id}}</p>
```